# Can you get commit information of a pullrequest using the pullrequest ID (without knowing the issue number)?

Tags: github-api

I have the pull request id of all the pull requests in a public repository. I was wondering if I could use this information to get the commit level information using Github api? I understand that this is fairly simple if the issue number is known. Unfortunately, i do not have the issue number for the pull requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub does not have any endpoints that allow you to filter using PullRequestevent ID. So, I guess the method you used by filtering based on type and date of creation is the best you can do for now.

Comment: Thanks, that is what i figured in the end.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is to search all issues based on repo name,type (:pr) and date of creation. Using the api, the above search would translate into - https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:km-Poonacha/testissues+type:pr+created:2017-06-16. I think one of the problems of using the id is that each pullrequest has an issue id and a different pullrequest id.